# Adrenaline vs epinephrine

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I just stumbled upon a blog that states that epinephrine is the American name for adrenaline. Is it true? If so, how prevalent is this Americanism within America? And do they prefer epinephrine in phrases like adrenaline rush, adrenaline junkie, etc.? What about situations where adrenaline is used not as a scientific term but a metaphor for action?

Comment: Epinephrine is not the American name for adrenaline. It is the medical community's name for adrenaline. It is used by the medical community in the UK as well.

Comment: Indeed, *epinephrine* was adopted first in Britain as a generic alternative for *Adrenaline* as the latter had been trademarked by the U.S. pharmaceutical firm Parke-Davis in 1906. See Tansey, E.M. (1995). [What's in a Name? Henry Dale and Adrenaline, 1906](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1037030/). *Medical History* 39, 459-476.

Comment: I think "epinephrine" is primarily used to denote exogenous adrenaline (ie, administered by injection), while "adrenaline" is usually used (outside of rigorous medical circles, at least) to denote endogenous adrenaline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**adrenaline**" and "**epinephrine**" are synonyms, and both words are currently used in medicine, anywhere in the world.

In medical contexts, in the U.S., you are likely to hear "epinephrine" more often than adrenaline.

In non-medical contexts, phrases like "adrenaline-charged", "adrenaline-junkie", "adrenaline rush", are "fixed" and I've never heard "epinephrine" being substituted.

Comment: In my experience, adrenaline is more common in America than epinephrine, which tends to be used more by the medical community, e.g. an "adrenaline rush".

Comment: I'm an American, and while I'm very used to hearing and using "*adrenaline*", I think I've only ever heard "*epinephrine*" in the context of an "*epi pen*". And even if you'd asked me to expand the "*epi*" in "*epi pen*", I might start mumbling half way through the word, even though I'd have no problem with "*anaphylaxis*".

Answer (score 2):

*Epinephrine* is a specific catecholamine, one of a whole list of *adrenergic* drugs.

http://www.healthline.com/health/adrenergic-drugs

*Adreneline* is a non-specific term that could refer to epinephrine in particular, but also (especially outside of medical context) to any positive chronotrope (agent that increases heart rate).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Adrenaline was at first a trade name, and like many trade names got picked up by the popular culture and became slang. Scientists and doctors are usually more careful to avoid adopting a trade name in this manner; hence, "epinephrine" to refer to the hormone produced naturally in the body.  These synonyms sound so different because one is built from the Latin "ad" (above) and "renal" (of the kidney, as in "renal failure") + "ine" (generic suffix for a substance, particularly a drug) and the other is based on the equivalent Greek "epi-" (on top of, as in epicenter, epidermis, or epidemic) and "nephr-(os)" (kidney, as in nephrologist--a kidney doctor) + "ine".  The adrenal glands are so called because they sit on top of each kidney.

Comment: Yeah, in many countries the word "aspirin" is not used as a common noun, since it's a trademark of (IIRC) Bayer.  I believe "ASA" (acetylsalicylic acid) is often used instead.  Trademarks often cause weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

Epinephrine and Adrenaline refer to the same substance. You can use either one. Epinephrine is a generic name given by the Recommended International Non-proprietary name (rINN), while Adrenaline is the name given by the British Approved Name (BAN).
*Adrenaline* is used in countries like the UK, France, Italy, India, Scandinavian countries, while *Epinephrine* is used in countries like USA, Japan and Canada. They are completely the same and are only different by name.

You can go to this link and read a little about the discovery of this substance:
[Jeffrey Aronson: When I Use a Word... Adrenaline and epinephrine](https://blogs.bmj.com/bmj/2018/01/26/jeffrey-aronson-when-i-use-a-word-adrenaline-and-epinephrine/)